# network drive mounts itself multiple times (win10, synology NAS)

Tags: windows-10, nas, synology, network-drive

I have a strange problem.
One of my network drives is mounted multiple times to different drive-letters, from time to time.
I have 3 network drives (git,home,common) mounted to (git)X:,(home)Y: and (common)Z:. All of those three folders are actually on the same NAS.
When I boot Windows 10 there is only one drive letter mapped to each of the network drives. But after some minutes, there are multiple other drive letters mapped with network drive 'common'.
I'm not an expert with network stuff, so I hope I get some help here.
Probably I have to change some settings in windows or on my synology NAS to get rid of that behavior. But I have no idea where to look or after what words to google ;-)
It's possible to disconnect the redundant mappings, but they return after a while.

Comment: If you unmap the drives, do they return after a reboot? Are you mapping the drives by using a script?

Comment: I used the functionality of windows10 to map network drive and checked the box to autmatically reconnect on sign-in.

Comment: Unmap all of the drives and see which come back unexpectedly.

Comment: Disconnecting all network drives and reboot, reconnect helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments on the original question, the following solution worked for you:

> Unmap all of the drives, restart your computer, then remap the drives.